# data is still in memory after removing from stack in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to improve my knowledge of C.

As an exercise I wrote a stack data structure. Everything works fine if I push N items and then pop N items. The problem occurs when I try to push an item again as the last removed item is still in memory (I think this is a problem).

When I allocate memory for the new path struct, the last removed string is still at the address which was freed after popping a data. 
So when a new string is pushed, the last removed and new string are joined.

Can someone please check the following code and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Other comments are also welcome. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 1000

struct path {
    char curPath[N];
    struct path *Next;
};

struct MyStack {
    struct path *head;
    int size;
};

int push(struct MyStack *, char *);
char * pop(struct MyStack *, char *);

int main() {


    char path[N];
    struct MyStack stack;

    stack.head = NULL;
    stack.size = 0;

    push(&stack, "aaaaaaaaaaaa");
    push(&stack, "bbbbbbbbbbbb");
    pop(&stack, path);
    printf("%s\n", path);
    // output is:
    // bbbbbbbbbbbb

    path[0] = '\0';
    push(&stack, "cccccccccccc");
    pop(&stack, path);
    printf("%s\n", path);
    // output should be:
    // cccccccccccc
    // but it is not
    // it is:
    // bbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccc


    return 0;
}


int push(struct MyStack *stack, char *path) {

    if (strlen(path) > N) {
        return -1;
    }

    struct path *p = (struct path*)malloc(sizeof(struct path));
    if (p == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    strcat((*p).curPath, path);
    (*p).Next = (*stack).head;
    (*stack).head = p;
    (*stack).size++;

    return 0;
}

char * pop(struct MyStack *stack, char *path) {

    if ((*stack).size == 0) {
        printf("can't pop from empty stack");
        return NULL;
    }

    struct path *p;

    p = (*stack).head;
    (*stack).head = (*p).Next;
    strcat(path, (*p).curPath);

    free(p);
    p = NULL;
    (*stack).size--;

    return path;
}
```

Comment: By the way, `if ((*stack).size == 0)` works just fine, but 99.8% of C programmers would write it as `if (stack->size == 0)`, the `->` operator is the expected syntax to use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `strcat()` in your `pop()` function. That appends the string that is at `stack->head` to your `char path[]`. If you want to replace the string, use `strcpy()` rather than `strcat()`.

Besides that, though, there are other oddities in your code. You are returning an `int` from `push()` and a `char*` from `pop()` but you're not assigning those variables to anything in `main()`, so why are they not `void` functions?

Answer (score 3):

`malloc()` does not fill the allocated memory with zeros, so here

```
struct path *p = (struct path*)malloc(sizeof(struct path));
// ...
strcat((*p).curPath, path);
```

you *append* the given string to whatever happens to be in `(*p).curPath`.
(This could cause a segmentation violation easily.)

Using `strcpy()` or (perhaps better `strlcpy()`) should solve the problem.